GitHub webhook payload $.pull_request.number vs $.pull_request.id difference
Having a look at GitHub webhook payload objects for pull_request in "Action type: opened" in the following Webhook events & payloads document, I found there're two properties looks similar but different.
properties of pull_request object
two properties, I'm comparing, that number property is described, but not `id.

id(integer): None
number(integer): Number uniquely identifying the pull request within its repository.

From the description, I understand number property is the actual identifier PR number, but what's the id, is it literally unique PR id?
See example response payload:
[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/1347",
    "number": 1347,
    "id": 1,
    "node_id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0MQ==",
    "state": "open",
    "locked": true,
    "merge_commit_sha": "e5bd3914e2e596debea16f433f57875b5b90bcd6"
  }
]


Good question. If you get a list of 3, are they id 1, 2, and 3?

Haven't tried getting a list of them. But tried to get values via workflow with PR #8 in my repo, and had looked at pull_request.id, which seems a unique ID within Github. See an example as follows pull_request.number: 8, pull_request.id: 1788332802.

So after all experiment, the answer for id is only unique ID of PR.
